# Need help to find the font

Tags: fonts

Look as if this is Desire font or castle line grunge. But some character does not match and in the castle grunge is there any without grunge font. I  tried in My fonts, What font, Squirrel website. Did not get the similar font. Any suggestion or help which font is this.

[image]

Comment: You can ask the author, there's a Facebook contact at the [download page](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/shubh-diwali-festival-banner-with-colroful-diya_5830519.htm#page=3&position=16) and a gmail at Behance

Comment: @Danielillo Thanks for sharing the link. But im looking for the name of the font. In the file the font is converted.

Comment: That's why I said: ask the author

Comment: @Danielillo ohh sorry i did not read it.

Comment: @Danielillo i found its just normal castile font. Thanks